# Php artisan server

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkF11.jpg)artisan is not starting my dev environment. After entering the "php artisan serve" command,nothing is happening,only seeing my cmd cursor blinking for a long time,without any response.

Comment: have you checked that a `php` process runs? what is your operating system?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Run command:

```
composer update
```

This will update and export directories and files and then run command:

```
php artisan serve
```

if `php artisan serve` not work try this:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

source: https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-command-php-artisan-serve-not-working-properly/

Comment: No error is showing,the cursor is just blinking without any result.

Comment: Thank you all! This " Php -S localhost:8000 -t public/" got the problem solved.

Answer (score -2):

`composer update` you can try again by doing it.
or
`php -S localhost:8000 -t public` you can try the command.

Comment: Please do not use any other language than english when posting an answer on StackOverflow